# How to load html from ajax into a object?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

So the server is sending a normal HTML document with `<html>, <body>` tags etc

But when I try to load it with jQuery some things are missing.

```
var newHtml = $(response);
console.log(newHtml);
```

`<body>` is not in it.
Any idea how to get a proper HTML document with all the original stuff in it

Comment: Not with jQuery, what do you want to do with those tags?

Comment: _"But when I try to load it with jQuery some things are missing."_ Can include `js` which loads `html` ? , server response at Question ?

Answer (score 0):

Match your html first using REGEX, then make it into an object :

```
response = response.match(/<body[^>]*>([^<]*(?:(?!<\/?body)<[^<]*)*)<\/body\s*>/i);
var newHtml = $(response[1]);
console.log(newHtml);
```